# Store values of mutually exclusive options in same argument in Python argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have a Python script that can deploy some software in three different environments, let's call them `development`, `testing` and `production`. In order to select which environment the script should work with, I want to use mutually exclusive flags, like so:

```
./deploy.py --development
./deploy.py --testing
./deploy.py --production
```

So far I have this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Manage deployment")

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group.add_argument("-d", "--development", action='store_true', required=False)
group.add_argument("-t", "--testing", action='store_true', required=False)
group.add_argument("-p", "--production", action='store_true', required=False)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Thing is, I want to have the environment in a single variable, so I can easily check it, instead of having to manually check `args.development`, `args.testing` and `args.production`.

Is there a way of having a common variable that the three arguments could write to so I could do something like `args.environment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `action='store_true'`, you can use `action='store_const'`, assign an individual `const` value for each argument and the `dest` option of `add_argument`, so that all the arguments in the mutually exclusive group have the same destination in the object returned by `parse_args`.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Manage deployment")

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group.add_argument("-d", "--development", action='store_const', dest='environment', const='development', required=False)
group.add_argument("-t", "--testing",     action='store_const', dest='environment', const='testing',     required=False)
group.add_argument("-p", "--production",  action='store_const', dest='environment', const='production',  required=False)

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
```

The output is:

```
$ ./test_args.py --production
Namespace(environment='production')
```

Comment: Maybe useful to add: You can also set a default value which is used if none of the flags is set: `group.set_defaults(environment="default value")`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 3 arguments, you can just use one with [choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices):

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Manage deployment")

parser.add_argument("environment", choices=['development', 'testing', 'production'])

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Examples:

```
>>> test_args.py
usage: concept.py [-h] {development,testing,production}
test_args.py: error: the following arguments are required: environment

>>> test_args.py testing
Namespace(environment='testing')
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I cannot, because I have other positional arguments, that's why I stated I wanted to use flags.

Comment: I thought that this might be a problem, although not necessarily? Why does it bother to have other positionals? Anyway, in that case your own solution seems pretty good for it :)